# Vue-cli 3 - Webpack 4: cannot load images with .webp format using the image-webpack-loader

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, webpack-4, webp

I am trying to load images in Vue components with the extension .webp

```
<v-parallax :src="require('@/assets/images/hero.webp')">
```

I added the [image-webpack-loader module](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader)

```
 yarn add image-webpack-loader --dev
```

vue.config.js

```
    const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
          use: [
             'file-loader',
            {
              loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
              options: {
                webp: {
                  quality: 80
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but I get an error in asset optimization during compilation

```
94% asset optimization

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                       18:57:32

 error  in ./src/assets/images/hero.webp

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

 @ ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-16f8e3e2","hasScoped":true,"optionsId":"0","buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/
vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/Home/Heading.vue 11:24-60
 @ ./src/components/Home/Heading.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"/Users/yves/Developments/myprojects/node_modules/.cac
he/cache-loader"}!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/views/Home.vue
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue
 @ ./src/router.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client/index.js (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

what's wrong with my webpack settings ?

Comment: I'm following the examples on the image-webpack-loader documentation, aren't you supposed to add file-loader to the `use` array before the image loader?

Comment: yes of course.. I missed ... updated the question

Comment: I guees I need to add ALSO the webp format in my webpack config rules test ...

Comment: does hero.webp exists in your assets? or are you trying to transform one of your jpg, or png's?, try calling the gif or jpg directly. if you're trying to call the webp, then your file is not being loaded using the loaders, because it fails your `test` clause.

Comment: Yes I have the image.webp in my assets  so I added the webp extension un my rules test

Comment: sure, but it also fails the point of having the webp option there, you define webp when you want your jpegs and pngs converted to webp on request. It's great that you could solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

change test .. to

test: /.(gif|png|jpe?g|webp|svg)$/i,

and here we rae

Comment: That worked for me. test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/, to => test: /\.(png|jpe?g|webp|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,